# How to refresh a shiny datatable with a button that runs a function

Tags: r, shiny

I have looked everywhere and cant seem to find help with what must be a common issue.

I have a `datatable` in a `shiny` app. I load data into it when it first appears. It consists of one column of text

I want the user be able to press a button that takes the data in the `datatable` and performs an action on it and then presents a `datatable` with the result of that function. The function (not shown) basically splits the single column up into several columns.

I cant seem to figure out how to run a function from a button that refreshes and shows the new `datatable`.

This is what I have so far:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(EndoMineR)

RV <- reactiveValues(data = PathDataFrameFinalColon)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDT({
    RV$data
  })
output2$mytable = DT::renderDT({
    RV$data<-myCustomFunction(RV$data)
  })

}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)


basicPage(
  fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
))
```

basically how do I allow a button on the page to run a specific function that then updates the datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `observeEvent()` and `ignoreInit = TRUE` so that the initial dataframe is rendered without the function being applied.

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  RV <- reactiveValues(data = PathDataFrameFinalColon)

  output$mytable = DT::renderDT({
    RV$data
  })

  observeEvent(input$my_button,{
    RV$data<-myCustomFunction(RV$data)
  },ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

ui <- basicPage(
  fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
    actionButton("my_button",label = "Run Function")
))
```

Comment: Thanks @Wil. So if I wanted to then add a few more buttons that acted on the dataframe from the first button would I just add another observeEvent(input$my_button2{
    RV$data<-myCustomFunction2(RV$data)
  },ignoreInit = TRUE)?

Comment: Potentially, but because you are using the same variable `RV$data`, they would be modifying the same object, i.e. they wouldn't be starting with the original one that you first read in to the app on run. I am hesitant to say for sure whether your hypothetical scenario would work without seeing the exact example and knowing what `myCustomFunction()` does and knowing what your desired output looks like... there are too many factors to know for sure if you would get the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you. Have fun;

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


dat = data.frame(id = c("d","a","c","b"), a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c(6,7,8,9))

header <- dashboardHeader(

)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 1500px !important;}'))),
  sidebarMenu (
    menuItem("A", tabName = "d1"),
    menuItem("B", tabName = "d2"),
    menuItem("C", tabName = "d3")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(

  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "d1",
            box(title = "AAA",
                actionButton("refreshTab1_id", "Refresh Tab 1"),
                actionButton("sortTable1_id", "Sort Table 1"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("table_for_tab_1", width = "100%"))
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "d2",
             box(title = "BBB",
                actionButton("refreshTab2_id", "Refresh Tab 2"),
                actionButton("sortTable2_id", "Sort Table 2"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("table_for_tab_2", width = "100%"))
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "d3",
            box(title = "CCC",
                actionButton("refreshTab3_id", "Refresh Tab 3"),
                actionButton("sortTable3_id", "Sort Table 3"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("table_for_tab_3", width = "100%"))
    )
  )
)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {


    observe({

        if (input$sortTable1_id || input$sortTable2_id || input$sortTable3_id) {
            dat_1 = dat %>% dplyr::arrange(id)
        } else {
            dat_1 = dat
        }

        output$table_for_tab_1 <- output$table_for_tab_2 <- output$table_for_tab_3 <- DT::renderDataTable({ 

            DT::datatable(dat_1, 
                    filter = 'bottom', 
                    selection = "single",
                    colnames = c("Id", "A", "B"),
                    options = list(pageLength = 10,
                                    autoWidth = TRUE#,
                                    # columnDefs = list(list(targets = 9, 
                                    #                        visible = FALSE))
                    )
            )
        })
    })

    observe({
        if (input$refreshTab1_id || input$refreshTab2_id || input$refreshTab3_id) {
            session$reload()
        }
    })

}

# Shiny dashboard
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```